# Router's Parental Controls Really Block All Internet Traffics?

Tags: networking, router, nat, wifi, block

I am using Asus 4G-AC53U router. When I turn ON "Parental Controls" to block a client's Internet access, does the router really block ALL kinds of Internet traffics including system's service (such as OS update checking, license checking, etc.) ? Or it only block normal user's access, e.g. web browsing, video streaming, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

This small office/home router has a function named "parental control" which is actually a simple time-of-day restriction for devices. During the times of day that you configure, the specified device cannot access anything on the network at all.

Comment: Yes, I know. I mean does it really block ALL of the Internet traffics? Including operating system's service.

Comment: Yes, everything is blocked.

Comment: Have you actually tested it?  I am not so confident about this.

Comment: Why are you "not so confident about this"? Are you actually having a problem? It would have been better if you had just asked about the problem originally.

Comment: No, but I heard that parental control is not 100% secure, some packets may still leak out, so I asked here.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on how it was determining what devices to block if it wasn't blocking all devices.  MAC addresses can be spoofed, etc.  If you are concerned about what your kids are looking at, a non-technical solution like putting computers with internet available in "family" parts of the house - living room, study, kitchen, etc. and not in a "private" space like a bedroom.

Comment: My concern is actually the device itself,  does the router really block ALL kinds of Internet traffics including operating system's service?

Comment: RRN - yes, it should simply drop any outgoing packets from the specific MAC address or IP or subnet.

Comment: ivanivan - Have you actually tested it?

Comment: @RRN No. But you could have instead of asking here.